# Analysis, Matrix Exponential, Infimum and Limit

Tags: analysis, applications

I was working in this problem for a long time and I didn't have success.

Someone could help me, please?

The problem:

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \times \mathbb{Z}^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
f(X,z) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} |x_i^{T} z|,
$$
where $x_i^{T}$ is the $i$-th row of $X$.

My question is:
If $f(e^{X}B, z) = 0 \iff z = 0  \;(B \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2})$ is it true that
$$
\inf_{z \neq 0} \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} f(e^{X}B, z) = \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} \inf_{z \neq 0} f(e^{X}B, z) ?
$$
Remark:

1. $e^{X} = exp(X)= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{X^{k}}{k!}$ is infinitely differentiable.
   I had a question like this two months ago, but the answered don't help me.

Comment: The answer may be yes, but a little useless. Notice that $f(X,z)\geq 0$and $f(e^XB,z)=0\Leftrightarrow z=0$, which mean $\inf_{z\ne0}\lim_{X\to 0}f(e^XB,z)=0=\lim_{X\to 0}\inf_{z\ne 0}f(e^XB,z)$.

Comment: @Vstal how can I prove it? I was tested some examples and I gave $\inf_{z \neq 0} \lim_{X \rightarrow 0} f(e^{X}B, z) \neq 0$ in some cases.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't your precondition $f(e^XB, z)=0\iff z = 0$ never attainable? There always exists nonzero $z$ for which $f(X, z) = 0$, regardless $X$.